# Simple question about linear congruence with Fermat's little theorem $4x≡11\bmod19$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

$$4x≡11\bmod19$$
How to solve this with Fermat's theorem? I know it can be done with Euclidean algorithm and Bezout's coefficients as well.
$$\gcd(4,19)=1$$
$$1=5 \cdot4-1\cdot19$$
$$\begin{align}4\cdot5x&≡5\cdot11\bmod19\\
&≡55\bmod19\\
&≡17\bmod19\end{align}$$
But with Fermat's theorem:
$$4^{18}≡1\bmod19$$
How do I continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

Little Fermat's theorem just helps you finding $5$ directly, the catch is that it is cloaked under the form $4^{17}$.

But you can reduce it by dichotomy and various tricks

$4^{17}\equiv 4\times 4^{16}\equiv 4\times 16^8\equiv 4\times(-3)^8\equiv 4\times 9^4\equiv 4\times (-10)^4\equiv 40000\equiv 200^2\equiv (190+10)^2\equiv 100\equiv (19+1)\times 5\equiv 5\pmod {19}$

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be a very good application of the Little Fermat Theorem, due to the amount of calculation required, as shown in zwim's answer above. Another approach would be:

$4x≡11\bmod19$
$\Longleftrightarrow 4x≡-8\bmod19 \Longleftrightarrow x≡-2\bmod19 \Longleftrightarrow x≡17\bmod19$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Multiply both sides of $4x\equiv 11\bmod 19$ by $4^{17}$.

Comment: ... but using Fermat's theorem is *way* more complicated than the alternatives.